# Grails JSON deserialization

Tags: spring-data, json-deserialization, grails-3.0

anyone know why grails 3 controllers have issues rendering spring data 'Pages' as JSON ?

```
Class org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk with modifiers "public
```